# Finally implemented my stack linked list in C, But Is there a easier way than mine?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, stack

I finally built my stack linked list. and it works fine.
But I want to know if there is easier and shorter way than mine.

I feel like.. mine is not the best way to implement stack linked list.

best way : easy and short.

my entire code below..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int element;
typedef struct node{
  element data;
  struct node* next;
}node;
node* head = NULL;

void push(element data){
  node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
  if(temp==NULL)
    printf("out of memory");
  else{
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = head;
    printf("push(%d)\n", temp->data);
    head = temp;
  }
}

void pop(){
  node* temp;
  if(head==NULL) return;
    temp = head;
    head = temp->next;
    free(temp);
}

void printStack(){
  node* temp = head;
  while(temp!=NULL){
    printf("%d\n", temp->data);
    temp = temp->next;
  }
}

void is_Empty(){
  if(head==NULL){
    printf("EMPTY\n");
  }
  else{
    printf("NOT EMPTY\n");
  }
}
void main() {
  push(10);
  push(20);
  push(30);
  push(40);
  printStack();
  is_Empty();
}
```

Comment: This would be better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Mat I joined that site, and just tried to upload my question. But it is telling me, "you can only post once every 40mins". Is it because I already posted this in stackoverflow?

Comment: Probably, yes. Just wait a bit.

Comment: `void main()` is not good C unless you work exclusively on Windows.  In C (but not C++), function definitions such as `void printStack(){ … }` do not provide a prototype for the function — you need `void printStack(void) { … }` to provide a prototype.  How do you get the value at the top of the stack?  Your `pop()` function doesn't return the value — there doesn't seem to be a way to get the values for use.  You mix I/O with a test in `isEmpty()` — that's not a good idea in the long term (meaning "when you go to use this code for real").

Comment: You forget to free data.

Comment: Error messages are best written to stderr, not stdout. For debugging messages, it depends.

Comment: Why do you feel like yours isn't good? The general idea is simple and effective. I would suggest, though, that you make `pop` return the value that it popped from the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good, but usually when you pop, you want to return the element you removed. Also, I would have a function that frees the stack so that if you wanted to create a level of abstraction, people can still manage their memory properly.